# How pass Image-path from tag to Vue Component

Tags: vue.js

I want to pass a image path from a tag that built by `Vue` to `vue component(MyPost)`:

```
<my-post txt="Such a great Framework, Rouzbeh Said!" url="image.png"></my-post>
```

I use parameter in component like this but didn't work:

```
<img src="{{ url }}" alt="post-picture">
```

My component in `Vue`:

```
<script>
    Vue.component('MyPost',{
        props: ['txt', 'url'],
        template: `
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card shadow-sm">
            //   this line didnt work
            <img src="{{ url }}" alt="post-picture">    
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">{{txt}}</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        `
    });
   
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `:src` instead of `src` to indicate that you have an expression and not a static text:

```
<img :src="url" alt="post-picture">
```

`{{` and `}}` should be used only in a tag content and not in tag attributes